# Center a 7 column layout in Bootstrap3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm starting to use Bootstrap 3 and chose a 12 column grid. I'd like my content to be 7 column large on large screens. Is there any way to set a 0.5 offscreen on the left?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can center any column size by using the proven margin: 0 auto; technique, you just need to take care of the floating that is added by Bootstrap's grid system. I recommend defining a custom CSS class like the following:

```
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now you can add it to any column size at any screen size and it will work seamlessly with Bootstrap's responsive layout :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! I guess I got too much used to relying on Bootstrap internal grid system and forgot my basics.

Comment: Wow, you totally copied this from another post.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `col-lg-pull-x` and `col-lg-push-x`.

For half a column, you could try creating a new class. Lets say you want `col-lg-7-5` you could set the width the average of `col-lg-7` and `col-lg-8`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just stick with Bootstraps grid system you can wrap your seven columns in a div and use the "col-md-offset" class. For example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>CENTERED TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>COLUMN ONE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>COLUMN TWO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>COLUMN THREE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>COLUMN FOUR</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>COLUMN FIVE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>COLUMN SIX</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
        <p>COLUMN SEVEN</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The downfall is you're limited to column size of 10. Alternatively, you can add some inline styles to fill the entire width of the screen like this:

```
  <div class="row text-center">
    <h1>CENTERED TEXT</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center" style="margin-right: 3%;margin-left: 3%;">
        <p>COLUMN ONE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center" style="margin-right: 3%;margin-left: 3%;">
        <p>COLUMN TWO</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center" style="margin-right: 3%;margin-left: 3%;">
        <p>COLUMN THREE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center" style="margin-right: 3%;margin-left: 3%;">
        <p>COLUMN FOUR</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center" style="margin-right: 3%;margin-left: 3%;">
        <p>COLUMN FIVE</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center" style="margin-right: 3%;margin-left: 3%;">
        <p>COLUMN SIX</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1 text-center" style="margin-left: 3%;">
        <p>COLUMN SEVEN</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

code pen here: https://codepen.io/dylanprem/pen/BrzKxo?editors=1010

Hope this helps!